# Install PyX under python 2.7.6

Tags: python, macos, pyx

I am trying to install PyX in yosemite under python 2.7.6

Initially, the setup looks ok

```
 python setup.py  install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /Users/alkaloge/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyX-0.12.1-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Users/alkaloge/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyX-0.12.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

but when trying to run an example

```
 python hello.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyx import *
ImportError: No module named pyx
```

Any help ?

thanks

Comment: At the command line, type `cd` to go to your home directory, type `python` to start the interpreter, then run `import sys; print(sys.path)`. What are the results of that command?

Comment: `['/Users/alkaloge/root/lib', '/Users/alkaloge', '/Users/alkaloge/Library/Python/2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',`

Comment: `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']`

Comment: Had to put two comments to include all

Comment: If you run `ls ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, which entries (if any) matching `pyx*` or `PyX*` or similar are there?

Comment: `ls ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

PyX-0.12.1-py2.7.egg-info          pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg                setuptools-11.3.1-py2.7.egg        test-easy-install-27332.write-test
easy-install.pth                   pyx     `

Comment: OK, so `pyx` is there. Try restarting Terminal completely and see if the import works now. There's no reason it shouldn't...

Comment: hey, I thought about this as well, but this does not solve it....

Answer (score -2):

Make sure, this is a common problem, your Command Line Interface is using the appropriate version of Python. Most users have multiple versions of python installed, and your CLI only recognizes one at at time. In your terminal window type in python and you will see what version you have. Also check where you installed PyX if it isn't under another python directory.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer to the question

Comment: This is the answer. Not a comment. If you have something better, please don't let me stop you from commenting.

Comment: trouble is, all the information is included in the question and comments. OP is using Python 2.7, and `sys.path` includes the directory where pyx was installed